# How to write ints with specific amount of bits in Java

Tags: java

So I want to write in a file integers with, for example, 10 bits each in Little Endian format. They also shouldn't be aligned to the byte.
The following image may help you understand the scructure.[image]

I looked at ByteBuffer (I'm coding in Java) but it doesn't seem to do this.

Comment: Normally, “little endian” refers to byte order.  Are you sure a₉ and a₈ are supposed to be in the second byte’s low bits, and not its highest two bits?

Comment: I'm coding a GIF encoder. That was an image I found about how the bits should be ordered.

Comment: You'll need to create or find a class that allows you to write arbitrary bit strings into a buffer. In the end they'll need to be aligned to byte, since that's the way computers work.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible by default. Java doesn't have a bit type, so the closest you are going to get is Byte or Boolean. You can make a util class with 10 booleans (as bits) in whatever order you would like, but other than that, Java does not hold this functionality.